# What's a better way to say, "I'm a TV whore"?

Tags: word-choice

A friend uses this **____**-whore construction all the time. I challenged her to find a better way to say it. I suggested *addict*, *enthusiast*, *devotee*, and several other words. She said none of these convey her meaning the way *whore* does. She says she'll watch anything. I told her she's not being paid to watch, and *whore* would imply that she is.

Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: Personally I'd say that a "TV whore" is somebody who portrays a whore on television.

Comment: @tobyink: Or perhaps someone who watches TV for money.

Comment: I suspect that this usage derives from *crack whore* which implies that the person is so addicted that they will do anything to get more; just as a traditional whore will do anything for money, they will do anything for crack, and your friend will do anything for TV.

Answer (score 7):

If you call someone a *tv junkie,* they won't be offended.  You probably won't even get their attention.

Answer (score 2):

> **TVphile** (compare with pedophile)
>
> > **TVholic** (compare with alcoholic)

These two come to my mind. If she is crazy about watching it, *fanatic* might work. However if she wants to denote the sense of leniency/low standards (as suspected)

> *casual couch potato*

could be suffice <s>albeit it starts to get wordy</s>.

It's her call after all!

Comment: I'd probably spell "TV-a-holic" or "TVaholic"

Answer (score 0):

What about *TV buff* by analogy to *movie buff* for movie lover?

Comment: A TV *buff* is not necessarily someone who watches it a lot. It is someone who is knowledgeable about the topic *TV* and quite interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Couch Potato** implies more than *just* watching TV habitually, but most TV junkies are couch potatoes.