# An abstract noun that refers to the quality of accomplishing something first

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun that means ***firstness*** as exemplified in the following

**Examples**

*Roger Bannister was the first person to run a mile in under four minutes.  Not many of us can achieve **firstness** in something.*

*Neil Armstrong exhibited **firstness** by being the first person on the moon.*

*Some people prefer to answer first in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer **firstness** over correctness.*

I thought of ***primacy.*** However the dictionary meaning doesn't fit -- primacy refers to importance rather than temporal 'firstness'.

I specifically want it to mean that the person achieves or completes something *sooner* than anyone else. Not that they achieve it better or to more acclaim.

**Question:** What is a noun (or failing that a short phrase) that means 'firstness' and would fit into those sentences without changing any other words?

Comment: Because it's such a polysemic word, actually using it might be awkward in a given context, but *priority* has the meaning you seek, as in academic discoveries and seating nobility at a dinner table.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like *competitiveness*.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks - That is an excellent suggestion. You might like to make it an answer.

Comment: @Robusto - Thanks, that is a good possibility wrt my 'wanting to be first'' option.  Note that I have since altered the question to exclude that meaning -- apologies!

Comment: *Pioneership* comes to mind but it is not a usual word to use for your examples. Although, I would suggest rephrasing your sentences to use *pioneer*.

Comment: Although it may be technically correct, I'm not sure that *pioneer* is idiomatic for the examples given. *Pioneer* suggests something qualitatively new, rather than just a quantitative difference: Calling Armstrong a pioneer sounds right; calling the speedy quizzer a pioneer sounds plain wrong; (and even calling Bannister a pioneer is pushing it, imo).

Comment: @ermanen - yes, pioneership is close. However you can't ask me to rewrite the sentences -- that would defeat the whole point of my question. It is the word itself I want. The sentences are just there to provide a clue to it. No point in the tail wagging the dog!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I didn't ask you to do that, I merely suggested. I don't think there is a word for it for your example sentences. No answer so far fits as a noun or they don't sound natural. As you see, the answer with the words "pioneer" and "pioneering" is the most up-voted one but they don't fit. Your sentences need rewriting in order to use them. The right form of the word you look for is "pioneership" but it doesn't sound natural when you use it in your example sentences.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I've changed my answer to meet your shifting criteria. The word you're looking for is prototypicality. Please see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/281500/129262 for references and examples.

Comment: I totally agree w/the OP that this is NOT a duplicate of the question cited (nor of any other question, AFAIK). My “Ooops” comment under my answer below shows that I, too, originally misread the question, thinking that it DID want the noun for such a person(which would be a duplicate), but a quick re-reading of the question made it clear that OP seeks a noun for the quality of such a person & not one for that person. The ‘evolution’ of my answer (see 2nd edit) might help to explain the difference (much more than a nuance) between “a particular person” & “the particular quality of that person.”

Comment: @PapaPoule - Thanks for your support. You could help me by clicking the **reopen** link if you so wish.

Comment: already did before commenting

Comment: @PapaPoule - Thanks. I've now made some edits to the title. I'm not sure I can make the difference any clearer. I'm glad that you and others have taken the trouble to read and understand  but disappointed that a few have not.

Answer (score 7):

You may be looking for [*pioneer*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pioneer) and pioneering:

The definition of *pioneer* from Merriam-Webster is:

> **a:** person or group that originates or helps open up a new line of thought or activity or a new method or technical development
>
> **b** :  one of the first to settle in a territory

So *pioneering* means being one of the first that thinks of or does something.

Comment: No, I do not mean 'pioneer'. A pioneer is a *person*. It does not fit into my examples at all. For example, you cannot say, "*Some people prefer to answer first in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer **pioneer** over correctness*."  Your suggestion of 'pioneering' is marginally better but I don't think answering first in a quiz counts as pioneering. Thank you for the attempt however.

Answer (score 5):

"Whether intentionally or not, John always seems to be out “**front, running**” ahead of the pack and “**blazing the trail**.”

The above notions kind of imply “firstness,” and derived from them there are: “**[Trailblazer](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/trailblazer)**” and “[Front-runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-runner)” for single-word nouns.

> Trailblazer: “a person who is the first to do or discover something
>   and so makes it possible for others to follow”

(from Oxford Learner’s Dictionary)

> Front-runner or frontrunner is a term used to describe the leaders in
>   a race, whether political or athletic.

(from Wikipedia)

Although “trailblazer” and “front-runner” might capture in one word the notion of “a person who is first,” neither of them capture the notion or characteristic of “firstness” that you are seeking.

Combining them, however, with something like “spirit,” “nature,” or “tendencies” to get noun phrases like “trailblazing/trailblazer spirit/nature/tendencies” and “front-running/front-runner spirit/nature/tendencies” could work in your first two examples with slight modification:

“Roger Bannister was the first person to run a mile in under four minutes. Not many of us have the **front-running/front-runner spirit/nature/tendencies** needed to achieve [what he achieved].”

“Neil Armstrong exhibited [his] **trailblazing/trailblazer spirit/nature/tendencies** by [doing what he did].”

Your third example would require creating a phrase with another word in order to make “front-running” work, like “reckless,” “compulsive,” or even “pointless”:

“Some people prefer to answer first in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer **reckless/compulsive/pointless front-running** over correctness.”

The only single word that I can see that could possibly work in all three examples would be “**[pacesetter/pacesetting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pacesetting)**,” and this only because it has two meanings:

pace•set•ter
… [related forms: pace′set′ting adj. & n.] …
n.

1. a person or group that serves as a model to be imitated or followed; leader.
2. one that sets the pace, as in racing.

   (from ‘American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.’ Copyright © 2011 and ‘Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary,’ © 2010 both via ‘The Free Dictionary’)

“Roger Bannister was the first person to run a mile in under four minutes. Not many of us can achieve pacesetting [pacesetter/setting status]/[be pacesetters] in something.” (definition #1)

“Neil Armstrong exhibited pacesetting/[is/was/became a pacesetter] by being the first person on the moon.” (definition #1)

“Some people prefer to answer first in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer pacesetting over correctness.” (definition #2)

Comment: Yes, so I could use the term 'trailblazing'  or 'front-running'. As in, "Neil Armstrong exhibited trailblazing by being the first person on the moon."  (+1 and I'll wait for others - I still like DanBron's 'priority')

Comment: Ooops! For some reason I answered thinking you wanted a noun for this kind of 'trailblazing' (the adjective) person and not, as you clearly want, one for the characteristic of 'firstness' itself. Thanks for kindly arriving at "trailblazing" (the noun) for me from my answer! However, with your kindness in mind,  I'm not sure that  "N. A. exhibited trailblazing by ..." (single-word noun) would work; but perhaps "N.A. exhibited his trailblazing nature/tendencies by ... ." would (adjective used in two-word phrase).

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with **first**?

> Roger Bannister was the **first** person to run a mile in under four minutes. Not many of us can achieve **being the first** at something.
>
> Neil Armstrong was the **first** person on the moon.
>
> Some people prefer to answer **first** in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer **being first** over being correct.

Comment: Ooh you had me there for a moment! That was until I checked my original sentences and realised you changed the wording. The thing is I need a noun whereas 'first' is an adjective.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm using *first* as a noun here, in the first two examples.

Comment: Then you should remove 'person'. The problem is that it's the third example that is the most important to get right. Still, 'first' as a noun is a good suggestion (+1)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK your comment conflicts with the title in the question, which categorically states *specifically completing something before anyone else does.* Now, you're often the first to “complain” when a user moves the goalposts on a question you have answered, so now I'm turning the tables onto you! Ha! Furthermore, to answer a question first in a quiz doesn't imply they have completed anything, they were merely the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

The word **anteriority** might work:

> **Anterior:** Occurring before in time; earlier.

(AHD)

Its synonyms **precedence** and **antecedence** may work as well.

Comment: Ambitious for a desire to be the first.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Oh, I see. Updated the answer.

Comment: +1 **Precedence** works very well in example sentence 3: *Some people prefer to answer first in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer **precedence** over correctness.*

Answer (score 1):

Consider *precursoriness*.

> precursor: something that comes before something else and that often leads to or influences its development

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precursor)

Answer (score 1):

I would propose *antecedence*, defined by dictionary.com as “the act of going before”.

Comment: Good job citing your answer, but your definition: *going before* does not always imply being first.

Answer (score 1):

In short, to be **primordial** or **primordiality** is to be first. Per *Merriam Webster...*

> **[Primordial:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/primordial)** first created or developed

Answer (score 0):

Tough question, but the noun *record* suggests being first in something

> **[record](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/record)** noun (BEST)
>   [C] the ​best or ​fastest ​ever done:

- Roger Bannister was the first person to run a mile in under four minutes. Not many of us can achieve **a record** in something.
- Neil Armstrong was a **[record-holder](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/record-holder)**  by being the first person on the moon
- Some people prefer to answer first in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer **record-breaking** over correctness.

Despite the comments below, the first two examples do fit, the simple fact is that both Bannister and Armstrong did succeed. They are "record-holders" in the sense that they hold the titles for being the first; likewise Joshua Slocum, Sir Edmund Hillary and Tenzing Norgay, the Wright Brothers, Wiley Post and Amelia Earhart. So, I'm leaving those two suggestions.

---

It now appears the OP is really interested in the third example, a pity he failed to mention this in the question, but he has been leaving comments saying that it is his *prime* concern. The third example is a stretch, if you said the sentence in a terse, half-sarcastic way, it would work. One could use air quotes over *record-breaking*.

Always wanting to be the first to answer a question, even if you're not sure of the answer isn't a very smart thing to do. I don't really have any experience with this type of behaviour, it's usually the same people who raise their hands first, or in the case of a Q&A website, post an answer first because they *do* know the answer. But on a Q&A website this type of obsessive behaviour is looked down upon.

So my amended suggestion, with a *noun*, would be:

> - Some people prefer to answer first in a quiz, even if they get the answer wrong. They prefer **rep-whoring** over correctness.

Related: [What's a less offensive substitute for “rep-whores”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226736/whats-a-less-offensive-substitute-for-rep-whores) The top two answers were: rep-hound and rep-farmer. The fact that the top answer was supplied by a user was **first to post an answer** just proves my point, users who post/answer first are those who already *know* the answers... well, most of the time.

Comment: I don't think your answer fits in there at all. Roger Bannister and Neil Armstrong were "a record" because they were acknowledged by people as "a success". If they had failed to do it, they would not have been considered as any record. If Neil Armstrong had been killed in the action by accident, he would not have been a record. The next one would have been the record. Furthermore, The word doesn't represent "firstness" over "correctness". They were all first and correct at the same time. It doesn't work.

Comment: And in the final example, there's no record being broken, either, so the word choice makes little sense, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be so quick to dismiss "primacy." It's literal meaning is something like "that which comes first," and is somewhat ambiguous on whether that refers to quality or temporality.

> **primacy** |ˈprīməsē|
>   *noun*
>   1 the fact of being primary, preeminent, or more important: "the primacy of air power in the modern war."
>
> **primary**
>   *noun*
>   2 earliest in time or order of development

You may also like "preeminence:"

> **preeminence** |prēˈemənəns|
>   *noun*
>   the fact of surpassing all others; superiority: "the region has never regained the economic preeminence that it once enjoyed."

(source: American Heritage English Dictionary)

Comment: You probably got a downvote for putting in "primacy" when the question explicitly dismisses it.  (I think "preeminence" is actually a very good word, though.)  However, you also need to supply your sources; quoting without attribution will get your answer deleted.

Comment: I ought to have made a better case for primacy to not be rejected. It may have been dismissed unfairly. 

But it doesn't matter as I now see I lack the reputation to even submit an answer here.

Answer (score -1):

A **breakthrough** ?

> Roger Bannister was the first person to run a mile in under four
> minutes. Not many of us can achieve **a breakthrough** in something.
>
> Neil Armstrong **made a breakthrough** by being the first person on
> the moon.

It is not great however for the last *quiz* example